# Rotating various objects in different axis

Tags: animation, transforms

I am trying to model kind of a helicopter rotor like this [image]

I would like to make it so that when I open one of the wings, the others open to. I want to make an animation like the wings are closed like this

[image]

and then open to the position that they are in the fistr picture, without having to manually rotate them every time. Any help?

Comment: Dont have time for full answer: R,Y,Y,90,Enter  (maybe X,X or Z,Z) - depending on objects axis.

Comment: Can you explain it  better? I've tried selecting all four wings and using the R, Y, Y, or the other axis and it didn't work.

Comment: Try changing the pivot point to "Individual Origins"

Answer (score 2):

You can add a driver to bind their rotation to the position of an empty:

1. Add an empty:
   [image]
2. Right click and `Add Single Driver` to the appropriate axis of rotation on your blade. Repeat for each blade.
   [image]
3. Open the graph editor and define your driver, for each blade:
   [image]

   I made the z location of my empty drive the x rotation of my blades.

Comment: I haven't got the hang of taking good screenshots yet.. hope those work well enough.

Comment: Thank you very much! But all the blades rotate in the same direction, there are two that need to rotate negative ways, how do I do that?

Comment: Forget it, solved with constraints.

Comment: K. You should post your alternate solution as an answer and accept it :)